# How can I copy a hidden directory recursively and preserving its permissions?

Tags: command-line, files, cp

```
mkdir backupcache    
cp -rp .cache backupcache # or cp -rp \.cache backupcache does not work
```

nothing gets copied and directory backupcache remains empty

Comment: are you sure nothing gets copied?  I'd expect there to be `backupcache/.cache` etc

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Don't specify the files or directory**

Let's say you created the new folder (or are going to create one)
and want to copy the files to it after the folder is created

```
mkdir /test/folder  &&
cp -rp /path/to/copy/. /test/folder
```

This will copy all files/folder recursively from `/path/to/copy`
into the already existing folder created on the first line.

Another approach is `tar`. For example:

```
cd foo
tar cf - . | tar -C /path/to/bar -x
```

Using `rsync`:

```
rsync -av src dest
```

Comment: how does the tar command works here

Comment: @munish tars up the current directory to stdout then pipes it to second tar for untarring stdin on destination.

Comment: My fave: `(cd {source dir} && tar cpf - * ) | (cd {target dir} && tar xpvf - )` which works with almost any version of "tar"

Answer (score 3):

```
mkdir backupcache    
cp -rp .cache/. backupcache
```

that way only the content (`/.`) of `.cache` gets copied, not the `.cache` part.